# I can't show images in codeigniter project

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I'm trying to display images that I upload to my FTP but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

First of all, I'm saving `"uploads/images/".$image['file_name']` in my DB to know the relative URL of the file.

Later, in the target view, I declared the `helper('url')` and `helper('html')` to use without any problem the next functions:

```
img()
base_url()
```

Having all this done, I call the image as `img(base_url($object['image_url']))` where `object['img_url']` is called from my DB with the correct structure.

I tried to use the `<img>` tag too, but the `src` doesn't loads correctly.

The url that I'm getting from the DB is the correct one, but if I load it at the browser, it appears a `404` error because there is no "uploads" class with "images" method. My uploads folder was created at root level of the project.

What I'm doing wrong? I had to change something in the configuration of the project?

Comment: Are you doing `helper('url', 'html');` or `helper('url'); helper('html');`

Comment: I'm doing separately... is that the problem?

Comment: It might not be, but they should be together eg: `helper('url, 'html');` in `autoload.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter routes all requests to index.php and looks for a controller. Try adding this to .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do I really need to modify the .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have .htaccess. Example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|fonts|products_images|shops_images|uploads|assets|robots\.txt|migration)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dobrioferti/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do I really need to modify the .htaccess?

Comment: Of course, I only showed you how the file should like. You need to set your DIR in RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|......)